# How do I only generate the first page of a PDF using pdfkit?

Tags: python, pdf, pdfkit

I'm generating my PDF with `pdfkit` and it's working great. What I'm wanting to do is only generate the first page of my PDF instead of all pages. How do I do that?

```
import pdfkit 

options = {
    'page-size': 'Letter',
    'margin-top': '0in',
    'margin-right': '0in',
    'margin-bottom': '0in',
    'margin-left': '0in',
    'encoding': "UTF-8",
    'custom-header': [
        ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip')
    ],
    'no-outline': None
}

pdfkit.from_file('resume2.html', 'resume2.pdf', options=options)
```

Comment: Do you want everything on one pdf-page or should it just stop after the first page is generated?

Comment: It should stop after the first page is generated. So if there are 5 pages, only generate the first.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think that pdfkit includes a function like this yet: https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/

Answer (score 1):

Use pypdf2 instead:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
infile = PdfFileReader('resume2.pdf', 'rb')
output = PdfFileWriter()

p = infile.getPage(0)
output.addPage(p)

with open('newfile.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    output.write(f)
```

Comment: This looks correct but I think you need `infile.getPage(0)` instead of `infile.getPage(1)`

Comment: Thank You very much , actually I am a bit new to pypdf2.

Comment: `getPage(0)` indeed returns the first page: https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/blob/master/Sample_Code/basic_features.py#L9